# Time oriented simulation

Tags: queueing-theory, simulation

A factory y has large
g number of semiautomatic machines.On 50%
of the working days none of the machines fail. On 30%of the
days one machines fails and on 20%of the days two machines
fail. The maintenance staff on the average puts 65% of the
machines in order in one day, 30% in two days and remaining
5% in three days.
Simulate the system
y
for 30 days
y duration and estimate the
average length of queue, average waiting time and server
loading that is the fraction of time for which server is busy.

the above is the question. according to my knowledge. I did the following

> Expected arrival rate=0*.5+1*.3+2*.2=0.7 per day

and

> Average service time: 1*.65+2*.3+3*.05=1.4 days
>
> Expected service time: 1/1.4 = 0.714/day

now what is the probability that the system is idle?

I did,

> p= 1-(0.7/0.714)=0.019 => 1.9%   but the answer is 13.33 %

how is it so?